# Have an actively running Node.js script detect when new file enters directory and act accordingly

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, network-programming, whatsapp

I have a simple Node.js script that uses [WhatsApp web js](https://wwebjs.dev/) to send messages to a chat.

I have another Python script hooked up to a camera that will run object detection and when it detects a cat, it will snap a picture and deposit said picture in a folder.

**What I want:** I want the JavaScript script is to detect when a *new* photo is deposited into this folder, and then message said chat.

I have the messaging part down. It's the detecting part when the script is already running which is the issue. Here is my code as is:

As you can see, this JavaScript script can read a directory for an image and send it off, but that's a one time thing. Any new modifications to the directory won't affect the script.

```
const { Client, MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const Client = new Client();
//...
// Logging into WhatsApp stuff I'm omitting for brevity
//...
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    client.getChats().then((chats) => {
               // grouptarget will be the target chat that the messages are sent to
        const grouptarget = chats.find((chat) => chat.name === '<Chat Name>');
        const catpic = MessageMedia.fromFilePath("./output.jpg");
        grouptarget.sendMessage(catpic, {caption: "beep boop cat detected"});
        console.log("Message Sent Successfully");
    });
});

client.initialize();
```

This works fine for a one-time thing, but I would like this to be a continuous process.

I essentially started learning JavaScript today, so I would appreciate some pointers.

**Alternatively:** one could have the Python script (doing the image recognition and image saving) to run the JavaScript script after the image is saved. But (a) this would require logging into the WhatsApp web application every time which means (to avoid [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) shenanigans) I would have to set up some authentication stuff which confuses me and (b) I don't really know how to do that either (but I am open to it if that is the easier option).

What should I be doing?

Comment: One quick option that comes to mind is to use the chokidar npm package to track changes to your directory. It allows you to efficiently keep track of file changes, including adding, modifying or deleting files.
So, every time a new image is added to the folder, chokidar will trigger the 'add' event and your script will send that image to the specified WhatsApp chat.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, to achieve continuous monitoring of the directory for new images and sending messages when a new image is detected, you can use the `fs` (file system) module in Node.js to watch for changes in the directory. Here's an example of how you can modify your existing script to achieve this:

```js
const { Client, MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const client = new Client();
const groupTargetName = '<Chat Name>';
const folderPath = './images';  // Change this to the path where your images are saved

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    const groupTarget = client.getChats().find(chat => chat.name === groupTargetName);

    // Function to send message with the latest image
    const sendLatestImage = () => {
        const latestImagePath = getLatestImage(folderPath);
        if (latestImagePath) {
            const catPic = MessageMedia.fromFilePath(latestImagePath);
            groupTarget.sendMessage(catPic, { caption: "beep boop cat detected" });
            console.log("Message Sent Successfully");
        }
    };

    // Watch the folder for changes
    fs.watch(folderPath, (event, filename) => {
        if (event === 'change' && filename) {
            console.log(`File ${filename} has been changed.`);
            sendLatestImage();
        }
    });

    // Initial message sending
    sendLatestImage();
});

// Function to get the latest image in the folder
function getLatestImage(folderPath) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
    const imageFiles = files.filter(file => /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/i.test(file));
    if (imageFiles.length > 0) {
        const latestImage = path.join(folderPath, imageFiles[imageFiles.length - 1]);
        return latestImage;
    }
    return null;
}

client.initialize();
```

This script now watches the specified folder for changes using `fs.watch`. When a change is detected (e.g. a new image is added), it will trigger the `sendLatestImage` function, which sends the latest image in the folder to the specified chat.

Make sure to replace `'<Chat Name>'` and `'./images'` with your actual group chat name and the path where your images are saved, respectively.

Additionally, remember that the WhatsApp Web API may have limitations or restrictions, so use it responsibly and in accordance with WhatsApp's terms of service.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy